# Hide html when included inside php if condition

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I would like to present some php with the help of html formatting.

My purpose is to print:

**Life status: dead (1850 in New-York)**

or (if not dead):

**Life status: alive**

The place and date should only by printed if the condition `$life_status` is set to "dead".

The following code works for the dead situation but not for the alive one.

```
<h3>Title</h3>
<ul>
    <li>Life status: <?php echo $life_status;?>
    <?php if($life_status="dead"):?>
        (<?php echo $date_death; ?> in <?php echo $place_death; ?>).
       </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

For the alive sitation, I obtain:

**Life status: Alive ( in ).**

How can I applied the php condition on "( in)."?

Comment: You are opening your <li> tag but only closing it if your `if` evaluates to TRUE. You should move the </li> to after your `endif;` so that the tag always closes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong operator. `=` is assignment, `==` tests equality.

```
<h3>Title</h3>
<ul>
    <li>Life status: <?php echo $life_status;?>
    <?php if($life_status=="dead"):?> // == here instead of =
        (<?php echo $date_death; ?> in <?php echo $place_death; ?>).
    <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
</ul>
```

(Note that I also moved the  outside of the if block to address the issue I noted in my comment.)

Comment: Thanks. I did the modifications. However, with two =, the condition is never activated. I obtain *Life status: alive* or *Life status: dead* only. It is strange because `echo $life_status` prints "dead" or "alive". Any idea?

Comment: Ok I fix it. The "dead" was a link and therefire didn't activate the condition.

Answer (score 2):

Your operator for checking if `$life_status` is dead is wrong. It is a single equal and should be double. Code below reflects these changes and implements what @AmericanUmlaut correctly suggested in the comment above to make your html actually valid.

```
<h3>Title</h3>
<ul>
    <li>Life status: <?php echo $life_status;?>
    <?php if($life_status == "dead"):?>  // This maybe the issue, wrong operator used to evaluate.
        (<?php echo $date_death; ?> in <?php echo $place_death; ?>).
    <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

In Php strings are not compared directly and may not give the results which are intended. Therefore, using strcmp(); function will do the work. It returns 0 when 2 strings compared are equal and is a case sensitive function.

In your case:

```
<h3>Title</h3>
<ul>
    <li>
        Life status: <?php 
            echo ( !strcmp($life_status,"dead") ) ? 'Dead ( '.$date_death.' in '.$place_death.' ).' : 'Alive' ;
       ?>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have used the Php Ternary operator known as Shorthand if/else. 
The ! will reverse the 0 to 1 if its true to show the Dead output and else will show the Alive output.

Php Ternary : http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Php strcmp() : http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php

I hope it helps :)

Regards,
SA